# What does .. (double period) mean in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm looking at the following code:

```ml
  type (_, _, _) t = ..
```

and can't find anything about it

Answer (score 3):

It's an [extensible variant type](https://ocaml.org/manual/extensiblevariants.html).

A variant type that can be extended later on. Copying the example from the doc:

```ml
type attr = ..

type attr += Str of string

type attr +=
  | Int of int
  | Float of float
```

Comment: use very sparingly

Comment: why use very sparingly?

Comment: it's a flexible feature but it can easily be abused. i think the one common use case is `exception` types, which is made possible using extensible variants.